# TCP/IP Establish socket from app command to device

Tags: sockets, tcp, iot, tcpclient, tcpserver

Question related to the best practices/patterns of socket.

Scenario: Send command from the app to the device
Communication used: TCP/IP

What should be done when sending a command from app to device?

[image]

Is that necessary to open a new socket (with the last ip/port establish by the device) ~ which I think the answer is no

or

should I get access to the server - find the specific thread which has the socket open (at least ideally) and use that socket to request information? What probably I thought here is to have a docker-compose (with two dockers within) and communicate from the first docker (which will be basically an API controller with GET route) to the second docker (server that handle the socket connections).

Any tips would be welcome for the clarification on App -> Device socket command.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you mean, but to send "commands" to one of your "devices" you first of all must make sure that all devices are uniquely identified. The unique identifier need to be known to the app.

Comment: Then for the communication to the device itself there are two ways: 1) Let the server be the central hub, the app connect to the server and ask it to send commands to the device. Replies goes from the server to the already established connection on to the app. Or 2) The server acts as a phonebook instead. So the app asks for connection details from the server, which replies. Then the connection between the server and the app is broken, and the app creates a new connection directly to the device.

Comment: [Continued] Either way, the connection that the app creates to send commands, either through the server, or directly with the device, is kept open until the app is finished.

Comment: When I mean "commands" is for example a request of single location to a tracker. Regarding your second point I guess since it's a TCP/IP communication - I cant access information to establish a socket and send a command on app side (I only receive the LAN information if I'm not mistaken like: 177.25.246.100', 60466).